# Query MongoDB using computed value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a little problem, which I'm unable to find a solution to.  Let's say I want to query a collection for a field value within a range.  However, the field value should have a computation done on it before being search for in a range.

For e.g.

```
itemCollection.find({interval: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }}).find(function(err, items){
        if (!err){
          res.send(items);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
});
```

Here, interval value is 2. I need to get the current date, add two days to it and get the date it will be in two days (interval value) and then check if the resulting date is in the range.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a sample doc from the collection?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - it sounds as if you have the range, and then you are creating a new date as (current date + 2 days) and checking if that falls in the range. Where is MongoDB in that? Do you mean that you want a query that checks if (2 days + `interval` value) is contained in the range?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is quite possible and easy to do (if I didn't fail to understand your question).

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+2);

itemCollection.find({interval: {
        $gte: startDate,
        $lt: endDate
    }}).find(function(err, items){
        if (!err){
            res.send(items);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
});
```